# The odds ratios of the variable and the interaction are pointing in different directions(logistic regression model)

Tags: logistic-regression

```
m1 <- glm(syll2 ~ level + slope + Subject_Code + 
                  level * Subject_Code + slope * Subject_Code, data = d,
                  family = 'binomial')
```

I have 3 independent variables, *level, slope, subjectCode.* The first two are both numeric variables and the last one is factor with 3 classes*(Man, KRa, KRb).* The dependent variable(*syll2*) has two values, 'Yes(coded as 1)' and 'No(coded as 0)'. I set 'subject_Code' as a moderate variable to see how it interacts with the other variables.

I got the CI and odds ratio with the codes below:

```
m1_ci = exp(cbind(OR = coef(m1), confint.default(m1)))
m1_ci = data.frame(m1_ci)
m1_ci$col = rownames(m1_ci)
colnames(m1_ci) = c('odds','ci_lower','ci_upper', 'nm')
m1_ci
```

Below is the result. For the variable *Subject_Code*, the reference is *Man*. When you look at the interaction(*level * Subject Code, slope*Subject Code*), You can see that *KRn* made more '*Yes*' answer than *Man*.

However, the odds ratio for the '*subject_Code*' variable alone shows that *KRn* give fewer '*Yes*' answers than *Man*.

How should I understand this? Thank you.

[image]